# Qt Creator doesn't have QtTreePropertyBrowser

Tags: widget, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator that is based on Qt 4.8.1 version. I found a decent feature for having properties table that has been implemented called "QtTreePropertyBrowser" widget via [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/qttreepropertybrowser.html) link. However, when I want to use the widget on my Qt Creator, I couldn't find it. Can someone please guide me on this or probably there are any other substitutes for this.

Thanks in advance.